# multi-line title in visNetwork

Tags: html, r

In R, How can I have a multi-line title in visNetwork? `\n` Doesn't seem a solution:

```
require(visNetwork, quietly = TRUE) 
# minimal example 
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3) 
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3)) 
visNetwork(nodes, edges, main ="multi \n line \n title")
```

[image]

Comment: Why there is no visNetwork tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being interactive `visNetwork` use HTML instead of standard plotting.
Use HTML's new line tag `<br>`:

```
visNetwork(nodes, edges, main ="multi<br>line<br>title")
```

To align on the left, or to apply any other style use a named list as argument for `main`:

```
visNetwork(nodes, edges, main = list(
                                 text = "multi<br>line \n title", 
                                 style = "font-family:Comic Sans MS;color:#ff0000;
                                          font-size:15px;text-align:left;"))
```

Comment: Tnx, Do you also know how can I align the title to the left?

Comment: Thanks for update. I also found `<div align=\"left\">title</div>`